# Предложение с конструкцией "в то время, когда"

Tags: пунктуация

«Локальная» конкурентоспособность (способность удовлетворять требования слаборазвитого и неконкурентного рынка) — это, как минимум, топтание на месте, в то время, когда реально конкурентоспособные компании во всем мире устремляются в будущее.

Мне кажется, что в данном случае нужно убрать запятую перед этой конструкцией:

«Локальная» конкурентоспособность (способность удовлетворять требования слаборазвитого и неконкурентного рынка) — это, как минимум, топтание на месте в то время, когда реально конкурентоспособные компании во всем мире устремляются в будущее.

Или она там нужна? Если бы был союз "в то время как", то все понятно: запятая нужна была бы только перед ним. А как быть в этом случае?

Answer (score 2):

Составной союз "в то время как" обычно не расчленяется. возможность расчленения союза в то время как обнаруживается при актуализации временного значения, особенно при включении слов как раз, еще, самое, именно: Я спросил об этом деда как раз в то время, как он замахнулся было вторым валенком (М. Пришвин). Такие предложения близки к предложениям с ***союзом когда (в то время, когда):*** Грибы по-настоящему начинают расти ***в то время, когда рожь выметывает колос (В. Тендряков).***

Если не поставить запятую перед союзом, тогда изменится значение: получается, что топтание на месте происходит именно тогда, ***когда компании во всем мире устремляются в будущее.***

Смысл в данном предложении не в том, что в этот момент происходит топтание, а в том, что ***«Локальная» конкурентоспособность*** - это топтание на месте( т.е. ***- бесполезное дело***).

См. [Академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=132#pp132)

[Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь. Д.Э.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138)

Comment: Но а по какому правилу эту запятую можно там поставить? По правилу разделения простых предложений в составе сложноподчиненного?

Comment: Поставить перед союзом? Или расчленить союз?  Запятая перед союзом стоит на том основании, что присоединяет придаточное предложение.

Comment: Вот я и думаю: можно ли ставить две запятые - одновременно расчленять союз и при этом ставить запятую перед ним?

Comment: Аленка, если все же смысл в том, что топтание происходит тогда, когда реально конкурентоспособные компании идут вперёд и обгоняют, тогда расчленяйте союз, если же в том, как написал я, расчленять по общему правилу не нужно. Две запятые не ставятся.

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с Вами, так более точно передаётся мысль:

«Локальная» конкурентоспособность (способность удовлетворять требования слаборазвитого и неконкурентного рынка) — это, как минимум, топтание на месте в то время, когда реально конкурентоспособные компании во всем мире устремляются в будущее.

Comment: Мысль ведь в том, что "локально"конкурентоспособные  компании топчутся на месте именно в то время, когда реально конкурентоспособные идут вперёд и обгоняют?

Comment: Думаю, да. Смысл именно этот.

Comment: Смысл,по-моему, не в том, что в этот момент происходит топтание, а в том, что «Локальная» конкурентоспособность - это топтание на месте( т.е. - бесполезное дело).

Comment: Возможно, стоит уточнить у автора.

Answer (score 1):

Очень мне не нравится здесь этот союз "в то время когда". Я бы заменил его на "в то время как" и не мучился:

*...это, как минимум, топтание на месте, в то время как реально конкурентоспособные...*

И даже если оставить это "когда", все равно вышеуказанная пунктуация кажется мне более естественной.

Comment: А если менять нельзя, если это только анализ готового предложения?

Comment: Я бы все равно оставил такую же пунктуацию, как для "в то время как". Разумеется,**"В то время, когда космические корабли бороздят просторы Вселенной"** — это немножко другой случай. ))

Answer (score 1):

**«Локальная»** конкурентоспособность (способность удовлетворять требования слаборазвитого и неконкурентного рынка) — это, как минимум, топтание на месте, в то время когда **реально** конкурентоспособные компании во всем мире устремляются в будущее.

Это СПП с придаточным сопоставления (а не времени), здесь сравниваются ситуации локальной и реальной конкурентоспособности. Такие  союзы никогда не расчленяются.

Comment: Абсолютно с вами согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Хотя само по себе полностью это выражение можно отнести также и к союзу, вне зависимости от того есть ли запятая перед "когда" или нет, но на мой взгляд само по себе выражение **"в то время когда"** более всего это идиоматика. И когда мы его употребляем именно в этом качестве (в качестве идиоматического выражения) то запятую не надо ставить. Пример: **"Знаете ли вы, что клубника относится не к ягодам, а к ложным ягодам, в то время когда арбуз является полноценной ягодой?"** Короче говоря, если мы не будем ставить запятую, то не будет никакого нарушения норм грамматики, как впрочем и поставленная запятая также будет согласовываться с грамматикой, превращая наречие "когда" в союзное слово в дополнительном придаточном предложении относительного наречия. Пример: **"В то время, когда наши космические корабли бороздят просторы Вселенной..."** (Герой Пуговкина из "Операция "Ы" и др. праключения Шурика")

Вот как-то так что ли.